# Scrapy Request - process one group of urls after another - can I use priority?

Tags: python, scrapy

How to make scrapy process one group/list of urls after another? I have two lists of urls. I have to process the first list including `item pipelines` and then I can process the second list.

Both should be processed by one spider.

I'm not sure if `priority` would help me.

> priority (int) – the priority of this request (defaults to 0). The priority is used by the scheduler to define the order used to process requests. Requests with a higher priority value will execute earlier. Negative values are allowed in order to indicate relatively low-priority.

Because I don't know if it just reorder `Requests` according to priority - it could end up by pipelinenig first urls from second list before last urls from first list.

Can I be sure that `items` from first list will be exported into XML (I'm using `XMLItemExporter`) before those from second list?

EDIT:

ERROR (@Wilfredo):

> 2017-11-23 20:12:16 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on
>   signal handler: > Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File
>   "/home/milano/.virtualenvs/eoilenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py",
>   line 30, in send_catch_log
>       *arguments, **named)   File "/home/milano/.virtualenvs/eoilenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py",
>   line 55, in robustApply
>       return receiver(*arguments, **named) TypeError: spider_idle() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) 2017-11-23 20:12:16
>   [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

EDITII:

```
# coding=utf-8
import scrapy
from bot.items import TestItem
from scrapy import Spider, Request, signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider


class IndexSpider(Spider):
    name = 'index_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.scrape.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in ["https://www.scrape.com/eshop"]:
            # for url in ["https://www.scrape.com/search/getAjaxResult?categoryId=1&"]:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_main_page)

    def parse_main_page(self, response):
        # get subcategories and categories
        self.categories = []
        self.subcategories = []
        parts = response.selector.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'side-nav') and not(contains(@class,'side-nav-'))]")

        for part in parts:
            part_name = part.xpath('.//h4/text()').extract_first().strip()
            category_list = [part_name]
            categories_ul = part.xpath('./ul')
            categories_lis = categories_ul.xpath('./li')
            for category_li in categories_lis:
                category_list = category_list[:1]
                category_name = category_li.xpath('./a/text()').extract_first().strip()
                category_href = category_li.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first().strip()
                categoryId = self._extract_categoryId_from_url(category_href)
                category_list.append(category_name)
                self.categories.append((categoryId, category_list))
                subcategories_lis = category_li.xpath('.//li')

                for subcategory_li in subcategories_lis:
                    category_list = category_list[:2]
                    subcategory_href = subcategory_li.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()
                    subcategory_name = subcategory_li.xpath('./a/text()').extract_first().strip()
                    subcategoryId = self._extract_categoryId_from_url(subcategory_href)
                    category_list.append(subcategory_name)
                    self.subcategories.append((subcategoryId, category_list))
        # Scrape all subcategories (then categories)

        # for sub in self.subcategories:
        #     url = "https://www.scrape.com/search/getAjaxResult?categoryId={}".format(sub[0])
        #     yield Request(url,meta={'tup':sub,'priority':1,'type':'subcategory'},priority=1,callback=self.parse_category)


    def parse_category(self, response):
        tup = response.meta['tup']
        type = response.meta['type']
        priority = response.meta['priority']
        current_page = response.meta.get('page', 1)
        categoryId = tup[0]
        categories_list = tup[1]
        number_of_pages_href = response.selector.xpath(u'//a[text()="Last"]/@href').extract_first()
        try:
            number_of_pages = int(number_of_pages_href.split('p=')[1].split('&')[0])
        except:
            number_of_pages = current_page
        if current_page < number_of_pages:
            url = "https://www.scrape.com/search/getAjaxResult/?categoryId={}&p={}".format(categoryId, current_page + 1)
            yield Request(url, self.parse_category, meta={'tup': tup, 'page': current_page + 1,'priority':priority,'type':type}, priority=priority)
        hrefs = self._extract_all_product_urls(response)
        for href in hrefs:
            yield Request(href, self.parse_product, meta={"categories_list": categories_list,'type':type}, priority=2 if priority==1 else -1)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        yield TestItem(url=response.url,type=response.meta['type'], category_text='|'.join(response.meta['categories_list']))

    def _extract_categoryId_from_url(self, url):
        categoryId = url.split('/')[-2]
        return categoryId

    def _extract_all_product_urls(self, response):
        hrefs = response.selector.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'shop-item-image')]/@href").extract()
        return [u"https://www.scrape.com{}".format(x) for x in hrefs]

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(IndexSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_idle,
                                signal=scrapy.signals.spider_idle)
        return spider

    def spider_idle(self):
        self.crawler.signals.disconnect(self.spider_idle,
                                        signal=scrapy.signals.spider_idle)
        # yield a new group of urls
        if self.categories:
            for cat in self.categories:
                url = "https://www.scrape.com/search/getAjaxResult?categoryId={}".format(cat[0])
                yield Request(url, meta={'tup': cat, 'priority': 0, 'type': 'category'}, priority=0,
                              callback=self.parse_category)
            self.categories = []
            raise DontCloseSpider()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, prioritized url (requests with higher priority) are taken first by the scheduler, to be sure you could set a lower concurrency `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` the reason is that if you use greater concurrency some low priority urls might have been downloaded while you were queuing some new requests, and it might give you the impression that order is not respected.

Another alternative (if you need higher concurrency) would be to define [a `spider_idle`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-idle) method (my bad, thanks to @eLRuLL for pointing this up) and yield the requests from the second group, yielding also a [`DontCloseSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#dontclosespider) exception, something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    first_group_of_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
    ]
    second_group_of_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/'
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.first_group_of_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.debug('In response from %s', response.url)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(ExampleSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_idle,
                                signal=scrapy.signals.spider_idle)
        return spider

    def spider_idle(self):
        self.crawler.signals.disconnect(self.spider_idle,
                                        signal=scrapy.signals.spider_idle)
        for url in self.second_group_of_urls:
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(scrapy.Request(url), self)
        raise DontCloseSpider
```

Comment: I've used download_delay which didn't helped but I like your second solution. Will try it soon. Thanks

Comment: I tried it and it seems like closed method is not being called. When I put breakpoint on def closed line, I see that this line is executed, but immediately spider closes without executing other lines.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik that is because `close` signal is called when the spider scheduler already is closed, you need the `idle` signal if you want to follow this method.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik I've fixed the answer

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the same. The spider_idle is not even being called before close.

Comment: It's because set_crawler is not being called. I use the newest scrapy version.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik yes, you're right, I've changed the code to reflect the correct place

Comment: Thank you but there is still some problem :) It returns the error I've appended at the bottom of the question. So I removed reason argument from spider_idle but it did not worked. Again, the breakpoint stops the execution on def spider_idle, but it don't go further. It closes spider in another step.

Comment: Are you raising the `DontCloseSpider` exception (I feel that removing the reason argument should be enough)?

Comment: Yes, I'm raising it, but It doesn't even get to "if self.second_group_of_urls:" line so I think there is no way to raise such exception.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik sorry about that, there was a mistake in my answer (a long time since the last time I used it), I've changed the answer adding a minimum working example it works with the latest version of scrapy, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, now it's really weird because your example spider works as expected. My spider doesn't work and, besides parsing methods, they are the same. I've appended it at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Hey @MilanoSlesarik, I see, probably it's my bad, please check that the `spider_idle` method does not yield anymore, but it sends the request directly to the engine with `self.crawler.engine.crawl`, change that and it should work.

Comment: @Wilfredo Yes, finally it works! :) Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik I'm glad it helped you. Thank you for your patience also  :)

Answer (score 1):

To make sure one request comes after the other I would do something like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = ['url1', 'url2']
    yield Request(
        url=urls[0], 
        callback=self.process_request, 
        meta={'urls': urls, 'current_index':0}

def process_request(self, response):
    # do my thing
    yield {} # yield item
    current_index = response.meta['current_index'] + 1
    if current_index < len(response.meta['urls']:
        yield Request(
            url=response.meta['urls'][current_index], 
            callback=self.process_request, 
            meta={'urls': response.meta['urls'], 'current_index': current_index})
```